# Split newline-delimited string into three variables, # newlines unknown

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

I have a string like the following:

```
string = "thing: thing\nthing: thing\nthing: thing\nthing: thing"
```

...where the number of rows (newline-delimited) is 4 at maximum, and 0 at minimum. I want to extract rows 2, 3, and 4 into separate variables. This will fail, though, if a row is missing. For example, I might do:

```
    my @tmparray = split ('\n', $string);
my $var1 = $tmparray[1];
my $var2 = $tmparray[2];
my $var3 = $tmparray[3];
```

If there isn't a fourth element in the array, the above will break. Any suggestions on how to better handle this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip the temporary variable and just assign directly:

```
my ($var0, $var1, $var2, $var3) = split /\n/, $string;
```

In the case of missing fields in your delimited string, the missing variables will be undefined. This is the same behaviour as if you had used an array. The way to define when a field is missing is that it will then be undefined:

```
if (defined $var1) {                 # field exists
```

You can also count the fields, which is made easier if you use an array

```
my @fields = split /\n/, $string;
my $count = @fields;                 # the size of the array
```

Note also that the split pattern is a regex (`/\n/`), not a string. If you supply a string, it will still be treated as a regex, but the quoting may confuse you. So always use a regex, unless you are using the default `' '` split on whitespace. See [`perldoc -f split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) for more info.

Comment: I can't emphasise this enough: ALWAYS use split /FOO/, $string instead of split 'FOO', $string; -- the two mean exactly the same thing, but this way you won't forget that (and neither will anyone else).

Comment: @VectorGorgoth Almost always, since splitting on a single literal space `' '` is not the same thing as splitting on a single space in a regex `/ /`.

Comment: True, but emulating awk behaviour is going to be WRONG WRONG WRONG if you don't specifically know about that functionality beforehand. In other words, if you know enough about perl split + awk to need that, you also know I'm lying somewhat.